Select Current Browser Tab when Modal is Opened in Angular
I have a scenario where in the 1st tab, I set a function to display the modal/component after 5 seconds:
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.openDialog(); 
  }, 5000);
}

openDialog() {
  this.dialog.open(.....);
}

Before the 5 seconds, I open a new (2nd) browser tab. Is there a way to return to the first tab where the modal is displayed?

There's no direct way to switch back to the first tab programmatically from another tab in a web browser using JavaScript. Browsers have strict security measures in place to prevent one tab from interacting with another tab due to cross-origin security restrictions.
Just an idea, what you can try: you can change the title of the first tab when the modal is supposed to appear. This might catch the user's attention if they have multiple tabs open.
